# Please explain the logic behind this program that uses recursion to calculate a^b (a raised to power b)

Tags: c

It's really embarrassing!!I just fail to understand the working of the following little program that uses recursion to calculate the powers of a number "a" ("a" raised to a power "b").Kindly explain the logic used behind this function.I don't understand the use of the "x*x" parameter,the n/2 parameter and the "n modulo 2" part.Please dissect it for me.

```
    #include<stdio.h>

    int foo(int,int);

    int main() {
      int a,b;

      printf("Enter number a and its power b\n");
      scanf("%d%d",&a,&b);

      printf("a raised to b is %d", foo(a,b));
      return 0;
    }


    int foo ( int x , int n) {
      int val=1;

      if(n>0) {
        if (n%2 == 1) 
          val = val *x;
        val = val * foo(x*x , n/2);
      }

      return val;
    }
```

Comment: Observe that *(square of x) power (n/2)* is *x power n* at least when n is even. Run your program in a debugger.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch How do I do that in Codeblocks?

Comment: Is this obfuscated on purpose?

Comment: If you don't know how to run the debugger, switch to something else. On Linux, compile the program with `gcc -Wall -g` and use the `gdb` debugger.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch  Here's a skeleton in my closet---I never used debugger before.Only some theoretical idea I have about it.Why do we need it?Isn't compiler enough?(I use codeblocks on windows)

Comment: You need to learn how to use a debugger because as everyone, you'll make bugs and a debugger is a nice tool to hunt them. It enables you to run a program step by step (C instruction by C instruction) and to query the call stack or the backtrace, to display variables, memory content, etc.

Comment: @SheerFish [Codeblocks Debugger Wiki](http://wiki.codeblocks.org/index.php?title=Debugging_with_Code::Blocks)

Comment: @DavidCowden That is a helpful link indeed,given that I have no idea about debugger.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch What link would you suggest me to learn about debugger?I use Codeblocks(Windows).Any StackOverflow page discusses Codeblocks debugger in detail?I am aware about the importance of debugger but never knew where to begin learning about it.Can you suggest something else like what David Cowden suggested?

Comment: @SheerFish: I don't know about and never used Codeblocks or Windows. I'm happy with Linux (using it since 1995), the GCC compiler, and the GDB debugger.

Comment: You may also want to learn more about formal methods. Consider using http://frama-c.com/ and its ACSL language.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch I wish I could.But to be frank I am not that smart yet to learn advanced stuff.Once I get a good foundation in C,I'll definitely go through what you suggest.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The idea behind this recursion is, that a<sup>b</sup> = (a<sup>2</sup>)<sup>b/2</sup>, and a<sup>b</sup> = a(a<sup>2</sup>)<sup>(b-1)/2</sup>.

Depending on whether b is odd or even (thats the `n%2 == 1` part), you choose one of these formulas to ensure b/2 or (b-1)/2 is still an integer. Note here, that the `n/2` in your code actually is (n-1)/2 for odd n, since integer division rounds down automatically.

This recursion terminates since the exponent grows smaller with each step.

Comment: can you explain Cobbal's formula a little more?If any number can be be expressed as a product term the way he has expanded x^23 as x^16 * x^4 * x^2 * x^1

Answer (score 4):

This makes use of the fact that a power such as `x^23` can be rewritten as `x^16 * x^4 * x^2 * x^1`

Now computing `x^16` is fairly easy, because it's just `(((x^2)^2)^2)^2` which is only 4 multiplications instead of computing `x * x * x * ... 16 times ... * x`.

Now notice that while computing `x^16` you've also run across `x^4` and `x^2` which you needed to compute your number. So in the end, you've computed `x^23` in only 7 multiplications instead of 22.

Now where the `n % 2` and `n / 2` come in to the picture is in deciding if the power of 2 is in n (in our example, is 8 in the binary representation of 23? no).

So you just iterate through the bits of n. You square x every time, and if there's a 1 in the current n bit you're looking at, you multiply the squared number into your result.

Update:

The trick to writing a number out this way is to look at `n` in binary. 23 is 10111<sub>2</sub>, or we can write out the place values `23 = 1*16 + 0*8 + 1*4 + 1*2 + 1*1`.

This means `x^23 = x^(16 + 4 + 2 + 1)` and thanks to the exponential laws, `= x^16 * x^4 * x^2 * x^1` which is what we started with.

As another quick example: take `x^44`. We write it in binary as 101100<sub>2</sub> so we can say

```
44  =  1*32 + 0*16 + 1*8 + 1*4 + 0*2 + 0*1  =  32 + 8 + 4
```

so

```
x^44 = x^(32 + 8 + 4) = x^32 * x^8 * x^4
```

we then calculate the following

```
1:   x^2  = (x)^2                     (from the x we are given)
2:   x^4  = (x^2)^2                   (x^2 from step 1)
3:   x^8  = (x^4)^2                   (x^4 from step 2)
4:   x^16 = (x^8)^2                   (x^8 from step 3)
5:   x^32 = (x^16)^2                  (x^16 from step 4)
6:   x^44 = (x^32) * (x^8) * (x^4)    (using results of steps 2, 3, and 5)
```

Comment: That mathematical explanation helped a lot to clear things up for me.Thanks!

Comment: If you are reading this,can you tell me if it is a mathematically provable fact that any number "x^y" can be expressed as a product term like x^b*x^√ b*x^√ √ b*x√ √ √ b.....x^2*x^1  just as you have expressed x^23 above.I mean,4 is root of 16,2 is root of 4 and so on.Can you give the generic formula in which any power can be described in such a product term?

Comment: Hey cobbal, in your formula you have cleanly expanded 23 as 2^0+2^1+2^2+2^4,but how can we express say a number like 25 that way?or 26?

Comment: @SheerFish I've updated the question, I think 23 may have been a bad example; 16 being a square of 4 is just a coincidence, really what is important is `((x^4)^2)` which is `x^8`, not `x^16`. Let me know if I can try to make anything clearer.

Comment: That's ok for now.Let me first grasp what you and Jens have already mentioned in your answers.Your last comment made things a lot clearer.Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

As you stated, `foo` works recursively. Why don't you go through it step by step? Assume `a==2` and `b==3`, you get

1st move

```
int foo ( int x , int n) // x == 2, n==3
{
int val=1;

if(n>0) // n == 3, true!
{
    if (n%2 == 1) //true!
    val = val *x; // val = 1 * 2;
    val = val * foo(x*x , n/2); // next step
}

return val;
}
```

2nd move

```
int foo ( int x , int n) // x == 4, n==1
{
int val=1;

if(n>0) // n == 1, true!
{
    if (n%2 == 1) //true
    val = val *x; val = 1 * 4;
    val = val * foo(x*x , n/2); // next step -> 4 * ...
}

return val;
}
```

In the 2nd step you return 4 which yields in the first step

```
val = val * foo(x*x , n/2); // 2 * 4 in the first step and this equals 8
```